# How to differentiate From Which Activity the current intent comes

Tags: android, android-intent

Form Activity Login I call

```
Intent intent=new Intent(LogIn.this,BRInfoActivity.class);
```

From Activity BrActivityList I Call

```
Intent intent=new Intent(BRActiviList.this, BRInfoActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("BRinfo", objBR);
```

And Now in BRInfoActivityList

```
Intent i = getIntent();
BrInfoEN objBR=(BrInfoEN)i.getSerializableExtra("BRinfo");
```

Now i want if(intent==BrActivityList)The last two above line execute otherwise does not.How to do it?

Comment: Try catch putextra as bundle and compare the string with if else

Comment: Can you give some line of code examples?@Oli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form Activity Login call this--

```
Intent intent=new Intent(LogIn.this,BRInfoActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("call_from","ActivityClass");
```

From Activity BrActivityList Call--

```
Intent intent=new Intent(BRActiviList.this, BRInfoActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("call_from", "BRActivity");
```

Now, when you get the intent, compare the "call_from" string in an if-else block! That's it!

Answer (score 4):

If you will start activity with 
`startActivityForResult()`. 
Then you can use `getCallingActivity()` to get caller.

Comment: Can u give me some line of codes and write it if(condition)?i am new to android

Comment: @decoder, in, let's say, `onCreate()` of your activity write this: `getCallingActivity().getClassName()`. Caution: this will work, if you started your second activity via `startActivityForResult()`, otherwise `getCallingActivity()` will return `null`.

Answer (score 1):

May this help you...

The new intent comes as part of `onNewIntent(Intent)`. The original Intent is still available via `getIntent()`.

You put whatever code you need to into `onNewIntent` in order to update the UI with the new parameters; probably similar to what you're doing in `onCreate`.

Also, you probably want to call `setIntent(intent)` in `onNewIntent` to make sure future calls to `getIntent()` within the Activity lifecycle get the most recent Intent data.