# i want to know which activity class pass data to a other activity class

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity class which will be called by two other different activity class by different parameter and this activity's work depend on by from which activity class it was called.So i need to know the activity class from which it was called.Please help me.

I am grateful to you for your help

Answer (score 1):

if you calling your activity by `startActivityForResult()` 
**than try**
`getCallingActivity().getClassName()`

**or**

You can **pass additional parameter** in `intent`

**like**

**inside** `callingActivity1`

```
Intent intent=new Intent(callingActivity1.this,calledActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("calledfrom","callingActivity1");
```

**inside** `callingActivity2`

```
Intent intent=new Intent(callingActivity2.this,calledActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("calledfrom","callingActivity2");
```

Comment: This only works if you call using `startActivityForResult()`. Otherwise, it will return null.

Comment: @Tarsem 1xupvote is +10 1x downvote is -2: 2x10-2 = +18 let be happy with his downvote :)

Comment: You answered an obvious duplicate, FGITW-style, with an incomplete answer. Then, after being told it wasn't complete, you edited it to contain the other answers already posted on the duplicate and marked as accepted. I'm not going to reward that. I mean, sorry, but this really is an exact duplicate. I did upvote the answers on the other question, though.

Comment: @Geobits as you wish ! i respect your point ! but now my answer is correct which can satisfied the this question ! but i think instead of calling answer as duplicate, question should be marked as duplicate !

Comment: I agree, and marked/voted for it to be closed as such.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can pass an extra string to determine from which activity the intent is coming from.
See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500519/how-to-differentiate-from-which-activity-the-current-intent-comes/17500813#17500813)

Answer (score 0):

The Answer given by Tarsem is work great. but i have find other way Using Shared Preference.

When you going to start new Activity, just store a string in Shared pref.

```
setPref = getSharedPreferences(ApprovalsActivity.PREFS_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = setPref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("Class_Name", true);
```

and when you are in other activty just get the value from shared pref

```
setPref.getBoolean("Class_Name", false);
```

and you can perform action regarding this.

Hope you get idea.If any problem you can ask :)